# asp.net membership - customize password recovery

Tags: asp.net-membership

I want to customize asp:PasswordRecovery control.  I am using asp.net membership to control login etc.

How do I change "from" email-address on the email that sends the new password?

How do I change the content of the email that sends the new password?

Comment: I just saw something like "MailDefinition" that is supposed to do what I want it to do.  Someone else can confirm.

Answer (score 3):

yes you can use Maildefinition tag

```
<MailDefinition   
 From="xxxx@example.com"
 Subject="your subject"
 BodyFileName="~/_txt/Recovery.txt" ></MailDefinition>
```

Create a recovery.txt file like this :

The password for your user account was retrieved successfully. Follows your credentials for logging-in:
UserName: <% UserName %>
Password: <% Password %>

and add this in your webconfig file after configSections tag

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network host="xxx@xx.com" 
                 port="25" 
                 userName="your username" 
                 password="your password"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings></system.net>
```

Gianluca Maggio Cavallaro